# Publishing Azure Cloud Services (extended support) from Visual Studio fails with "The language expression property 'slotType' doesn't exist"

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-cloud-services

I'm following [the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/azure/cloud-services-extended-support?view=vs-2022) on publishing an Azure Cloud Services (extended support) instance from Visual Studio. However, publishing fails, with the following output:

```
22:25:06 - Uploading 'E:\Projects\MyCloudService\bin\Release\app.publish\MyCloudService.cspkg' as 'MyCloudService-3b0df582.cspkg' to storage account...
22:25:44 - Uploading 'E:\Projects\MyCloudService\bin\Release\app.publish\ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg' as 'ServiceConfiguration.Cloud-3b0df582.cscfg' to storage account...
22:25:44 - Checking if all the certificates exist in key vault 'https://mykeyvault.vault.azure.net/'...
22:25:46 - Preparing deployment for MyCloudService_2023-07-16T222446 with Subscription ID '...' using Resource Management URL 'https://management.azure.com/'...
22:25:46 - Starting...
22:26:12 - Deployment Status: Failed.
22:26:12 - The deployment through Azure Resource Management failed.
Code: DeploymentFailed
Message: At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.
Detail: Unable to process template language expressions for resource '<resource ID>' at line '1' and column '8784'. 'The language expression property 'slotType' doesn't exist, available properties are 'loadBalancerConfigurations, swappableCloudService'.'
```

The publish profile does contain `<AzureSlot>Production</AzureSlot>` though, what VS added during this publish attempt (it wasn't there previously), but removing it or changing to `<AzureSlot>Staging</AzureSlot>` doesn't help.

This looks like an issue with an ARM template. There's a deployment template generated under bin\Release folder of the project, and a parameter file, and these indeed have references to `slotType`. Trying to fix this from generated files that are overwritten before the next publish anyway seems futile though.

The same happens if I create a new publish profile.

This used to work without issues in the first days of April (I know I published once successfully then). Now if I try to publish that old code, I get the same error. So I suspect a VS update broke it.

Anybody with some hints?

Also posted this to the [Microsoft Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Publishing-Azure-Cloud-Services-extende/10416946) in case it's a VS bug.

Comment: Did you try to publish a new project?

Comment: No, I just tried to publish the existing project.

Comment: Are you using latest version of VS?

Comment: Delete the old published profile and try to publish again. And I can see only production [Azure Slot/Environment](https://i.imgur.com/XeMqHSy.png) is available for few locations. And few locations seems to be supporting both the [slots(production & staging)](https://i.imgur.com/z4lnDBr.png). I was getting the same [error](https://i.imgur.com/0pIW10l.png) when I tried to deploy selecting Staging, however I could publish successfully with [production](https://i.imgur.com/zfJU0QC.png).

Comment: Yes, I'm using the latest VS (17.6.5).

I tried creating a new publish profile, but the same XMLs are created, with the same results.

Since I could deploy to this exact cloud service 3 months ago, it shouldn't be an issue with the location. I also tried publishing with the Production config but that didn't help.

Are you sure you also get the slotType error? Your screenshot doesn't show that part.

Answer (score 0):

This is a VS bug, see [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Publishing-Azure-Cloud-Services-extende/10416946) in the Microsoft Developer Community. According to Devin Breshears from Microsoft:

> I think I have a theory on the root cause and will attempt to setup a
> repro and figure out a fix. I believe the template is looking for the
> Slottype property off of the networkProfile for the swappable cloud
> service. Since your swappable Cloud Service doesn’t have a SlotType
> yet, it fails.
>
> VIP swap is definitely a different implementation than classic which
> had slots as you mentioned. The SlotType metadata on Cloud Services
> (extended support) was added well after initial release and required
> an API update in VS (17.6) with a bunch of logic for when a service
> has or doesn’t have slottype. Looks like we might have missed this one
> when we have a swappable pair setup earlier and neither have a
> slotType in their network profile, sorry about this.
>
> You might be able to workaround, if you have the luxury to delete
> services and then recreate them. That should create the property we
> are looking for in the services. Line 271 seems to be the issue (at
> least that is my theory currently). This is where the template
> attempts to get the “swappable” Cloud Services
> networkProfile.slotType.
>
> FWIW, I am working on a seperate issue where we also get IPaddress
> conflicts when deleting a staging service setup as a swappable pair,
> then recreating that service and deploying it from VS, setting it to
> swap with the production service. VS will unfortunately try to create
> an IPAddress name that is already in use , such as what you mentioned
> in the portal. If you keep both staging and production services
> running, you won’t hit this.