# Publishing Azure Cloud Services (extended support) from Visual Studio fails - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-deployment

> **NOTE:** This is not your typical null reference error!
> The error is a message in the output of the *Microsoft Azure Activity Log* and is not from code directly in the project that I can debug.

I have a Web Role project that has been publishing to [Azure Cloud Services (extended support)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/azure/cloud-services-extended-support?view=vs-2022) instance from Visual Studio. This has been working for many years. Since December 2023 I have not been able to deploy to Azure, this is the *Microsoft Azure Activity Log* output from the deployment:

```
3:53:58 PM - Uploading '...\app.publish\test.cspkg' as 'test-2f8682e7.cspkg' to storage account...
3:55:05 PM - Uploading '...\app.publish\ServiceConfiguration.Test.cscfg' as 'ServiceConfiguration.Test-2f8682e7.cscfg' to storage account...
3:55:05 PM - Checking if all the certificates exist in key vault 'https://testeskv.vault.azure.net/'...
3:55:06 PM - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

VS 2022 Enterprise: v17.8.3
Microsoft Azure Tools: v2.9

If I remove the certificate from the key vault then the deployment stops with the following message:

```
10:32:45 AM - Uploading '...\app.publish\test.cspkg' as 'FinPalApp.DocumentGenerator.Website.Azure-14a25f38.cspkg' to storage account...
10:33:53 AM - Uploading '...\app.publish\ServiceConfiguration.Test.cscfg' as 'ServiceConfiguration.Test-14a25f38.cscfg' to storage account...
10:33:53 AM - Checking if all the certificates exist in key vault 'https://demodocumentgeneratorkv.vault.azure.net/'...
10:33:53 AM - Error: certificate: ‘Certificate1’ with thumbprint: 27AC9369FAF25207BB2627CEFACCBE4EF9C319B8 for role: Test is not present in the key vault: https://testeskv.vault.azure.net/
```

This verifies that the *List* permissions are correctly set on the key vault and that the failure occurs *after* the certificate check. I suspect the failure is therefore during the network configuration or something else.

I did attempt to increase the log detail, but this didn't provide any further information in the output:
[image: increase log verbosity]

I have also tried disabling remote desktop but that has also not made a difference.

Last year I did experience issues using the staging VIP swap slot that were equally hard to diagnose, similar to this post: [Publishing Azure Cloud Services (extended support) from Visual Studio fails with "The language expression property 'slotType' doesn't exist"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76700330/1690217) so I am aware that recent updates to *Azure Tools*, *Visual Studio* or the templates and scripts associated with deploying the extended support web roles.

**Question: How can I fix this issue or is there a new method to deploy web roles in extended support.**

> I am actively looking into alternate deployment configurations to remove dependence on this legacy service but I am hoping there is someone else who has experienced this and can offer some assistance.

Comment: Can you please share your Code repo?

Comment: `Error: certificate: ‘Certificate1’ with thumbprint: **** for role: Test is not present in the key vault: https://testeskv.vault.azure.net/`.Your code is configured to use the certificate from the Key Vault.But you have deleted it. It's difficult to find out until you share your code.

Comment: Thanks @Harshitha I posted that to show that certificate was _not_ the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was reported in a developer community post: [Cloud Service (Extended Support) publishing fails with object reference error](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Cloud-Service-Extended-Support-publish/10516204?sort=active&topics=16.7+preview+3)

**The issue was fixed in the release on Feb 13th 2024 — [Visual Studio 2022 version 17.9.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes#17.9.0)** and was available in earlier preview builds.

Updating to the latest solved this issue.

---

The issue post goes through the technique of debugging these types of issues:

> [Debug Visual Studio](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Cloud-Service-Extended-Support-publish/10516204#T-N10520968)
> ... launch a seperate instance of Visual Studio, then before publish, use the debug -> Attach to Process menu and attach to the other instance of devenv.exe. Continue the publish and when the Null reference occurs, the debugger should stop at that location

> [Additional Info](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Cloud-Service-Extended-Support-publish/10516204#T-N10521032)
> uncheck *"Just my code"* in Tools->Options->Debugging->General. Also In the *"Attach to:"* section of the *Attach to Process* dialog, ensure you have *"Automatic:Managed (.NET 4x) code"* selected.

The code where the error was raised from:
[image: Screenshot of Null reference point in code]

StackTrace:

> at Microsoft.Cct.DiagnosticsConfigurationHelper.FillInConfigXml(String originalPublicConfig, String originalPrivateConfig, BlobServiceClient blobClient, String connectionString, String storageType) in Microsoft.Cct\DiagnosticsConfigurationHelper.cs:line 210

CallStack:

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.WindowsAzure.2.9.dll! Microsoft.Cct.DiagnosticsConfigurationHelper.FillInConfigXml(string originalPublicConfig, string originalPrivateConfig, Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobServiceClient blobClient, string connectionString, string storageType) Line 210    C#
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.WindowsAzure.2.9.dll! Microsoft.Cct.DiagnosticsConfigurationHelper.FillStorageKeyIfNeededAsync(string originalPublicConfig, string originalPrivateConfig, string roleName, Microsoft.Cct.ServiceModel.ServiceModelView serviceModel, string serviceConfiguration, Microsoft.VisualStudio.WindowsAzure.ResourceManagement.IAzureSubscriptionContextWrapper context, string fallbackAccountName) Line 171  C#
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.WindowsAzure.2.9.dll! Microsoft.Cct.CctProjectConfig.CreateRoleDiagnosticsConfigMappingAsync(Microsoft.VisualStudio.WindowsAzure.ResourceManagement.IAzureSubscriptionContextWrapper context) Line 1244  C#
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.WindowsAzure.2.9.dll! Microsoft.Cct.CctProjectConfig.PrepareAzureRMDeployment(Microsoft.VisualStudio.WindowsAzure.ResourceManagement.IAzureSubscriptionContextWrapper context, Microsoft.Cct.ResourceManagement.AzureRMClient armClient, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Deployment.AzureDeploymentSettings settings, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Deployment.IAzureCustomDeploymentNotification deployNotification, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancelToken) Line 830   C#